# Create a docker group and place my user in it in MacOS

Tags: linux, docker, macos

Following [Docker's installation instructions](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/) for Linux on a MacBook, since there isn't a dedicated page for MacOs, I am unable to create the docker group and assign myself to it:

```
 sudo groupadd docker
 sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
```

Since both groupadd and usermod commands are unidentified in mac.

What are the macOS alternatives?

Comment: You don't usually need to do this at all: the user who launched the Docker Desktop application will be able to use `docker` commands without `sudo` already.

Comment: @DavidMaze - So this section in Docker's installation is not required?

Comment: You're reading Linux installation instructions but you're on a MacOS host.

Comment: Unfortunately true, not that I had an alternative

Answer (score 1):

The solution was found to be the [dscl](https://www.unix.com/man-page/osx/1/dscl/) command.

And specifically:

```
sudo dscl . create /Groups/docker GroupMembership userName
```

with userName being the user I want to put in the docker group.